# Cascade delete (potentially null) collection with EF CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have this class:

```
public class Participant
  {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual PersonName Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ResponseSet> SurveyResponses { get; set; }
  }
```

When the participant is first created there won't be any survey responses (so I don't think the answer is to make this collection required).  However, I'd like to have a cascading delete on all ResponeSets in SurveyResponses if I delete a Participant.  I added this to my DbContext:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Participant>()
                    .HasOptional(d=>d.SurveyResponses)
                    .WithMany()
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
      }
```

But this doesn't quite work.  Yes, it has created cascading deletes.  But it's just added a SurveyResponses_Id FK on the Participants table.  Unless I'm missing something that's not what I'm trying to do because the Participant can have more than 1 ResponseSet in the collection.

Unfortunately, I've found a lot of answers to this question but none of them seem to deal with collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the relationship between Person and Response Surveys is 1:n. Because that the foreign key of person must be in the Response survey table. The collection Survey responses is just a navigation property and not have really a column representation in the database.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ResponseSet>()
        .HasRequired(s =>s.Participant)
        .WithMany(s =>s.SurveyResponses)
        .Map(s =>s.MapKey("ParticipantId"))
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't work.  Do I need to restructure my classes to do this?

Comment: Could you please write your pocos to help you? (Are you writing Participant model builder also? don't do that)

Comment: No, this is the only use I'm making of the Fluent API.  Does the ResponseSet class need to reference Participant somehow?  It does't right now.

Comment: Yes because one Responset need a participant (and that is what is in my answer with the HasRequired)

Comment: Well, OK.  What I had did (before adding the OnModelCreate stuff) build the proper association, except nullable and without the cascade.

Comment: It's very strange I replicate with my "home made classes" your example (I invent the structure of the PersonName and Response set) and it works. After you execute your program and it created the database open the database and execute "select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS" to see the constraints

Comment: I'm looking at the database through the Server Explorer.  While there is a constraint on the Participant_Id field, the field is also nullable and no cascade delete is there.  I added a reference to Participant in ResponseSet and then added the code you have here but it doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I was having some problems with the local SQL database.  Your solution *does* work.